# Advice on design of a Wind Turbine system

Tags: usb, brushless-dc-motor, windturbine

I am currently doing GDP at university. Our project is about creating a portable wind turbine which can be used to charge phones and batteries via USB output (5V). As mechanical engineers we don't have much knowledge in designing circuits and electronics overall so we need help.

How would I go about designing a wind turbine system rated at a few Watts DC output in moderate winds (say 5 to 10 m/s) to provide 5V / USB output.

I also believe that we would need to use a gearbox in our design. I'd appreciate advice on how to identify available components that are suited to our requirement. (We are ideally looking for budget friendly components available in the UK.)

I would also much appreciate any sources which I can use to improve my knowledge about things I need in this project.

Comment: On the face of it you’re asking exactly the questions that it’s the point of the exercise to learn.  What kind of generator should you use, how should you optimise its output and in particular how fast should you run it.  I suggest that you look at some generator topologies and go from there.

Comment: Also as *Are there any known companies* calls for recommendations, it is not part of EE's Q&A concept: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: If on Facebook: Join this proup - https://www.facebook.com/groups/693332237389799/ Say hello and state your need. (What's GDP?) ||  Possisbly also [here](https://www.facebook.com/groups/1177340572444197/) || The 1st has some REALLY competent informed members. (Also me maybe orthogonally :-) ). | How much power wanted? What target wind ranges? || BLDC - 3 phase rectifier - usually no gearbox. Simple overvoltage controller and battery charger if small. Overspeed load dump control if not tiny. Making your own alternator & turbine may be easier than you expect. || Power wanted affects decisions.

Comment: NBNBNB: IF this question is closed it can be reopened if questions are answered.  It has the making of a good question. Specifying power, environment, wind speed expectations helps. Cost limits? Charging time hopes? Phone battery size? || Power = 0.6 x Area_m^2 x Wind velocity^3 m/s x efficiency. Start with efficiency = 0.1 to 0.15.  So eg 5 m/s, 1 sq m. || P= 0.6 x 1 x 5^3 x 0.15 =~~ 10 Watts. || 3.3 Ah battery (larger cellphone) x 5V into charger ~= 17 Wh. Charge in under 2 hours (longer due to LiIon charging tail). Very doable. Or 2 x 1000 mAh in 1 hour to 80% + .

Comment: Your question was closed. I have heavily edited and reopened it.  PLEASE provide substantially more detail of your expectations. Power. Cost maybe. Likely wind speed range (if you don't know that then it cant be sensibly designed) , and operation location . The better the spec the better the answers can be.

Comment: Used Fisher & Paykel "Smart Drive" washing machine motor - may be free. Bigger than some. Hoverboard, escooter, ebike (non geared) motor. Battery weed wiper, ... . All possible alternator sources. Avoided vrushed motors of possible. The lower the speed NON GEARED the better. F&P motor is superb.

Comment: [Fisher & Paykel](https://www.google.com/search?q=fisher+and+paykel+wind+turbine&sca_esv=578293274&tbm=isch&sxsrf=AM9HkKnTplBO57XcWBYaB0mXU2MektlQBA:1698796443363&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiOobX0vaGCAxWgTmwGHbTbDvoQ_AUoAnoECAIQBA&biw=2194&bih=1077&dpr=1.75) motor used in wind turbine and similar - image search. Many links.

Comment: **G**lobal **D**iscovery **P**rogam / *Discovery Program for Global Learners* is obscure compared to *Gross/Green Domestic Product*: Please edit intended meaning into your post.

Comment: (`a few Watts` matches the requirements for a bicycle alternator. A front wheel with radial spokes (and a hub generator…) can be turned into a US multiblade style "turbine" with some adhesive film.)